# create an Java api that will manually trigger Kubernetes already created jobs

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, kubernetes, kubectl

I have a job already running in `Kubernates` which is scheduled for 4 hours. But I need to write a Java API so that whenever I want to run the job I just need to call this API and it runs the Job.

Please help to solve this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is two way either you run your application in POD which create JOB for you OR you write java API and when you hit endpoint, it will create the job that time.

For creation, you can use the Java Kubernetes client library.

Example - [Click here](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/JobExample.java)

Java client - [Click here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java)

```
package io.fabric8.kubernetes.examples;

import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.PodList;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.batch.v1.Job;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.batch.v1.JobBuilder;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.ConfigBuilder;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/*
 * Creates a simple run to complete job that computes π to 2000 places and prints it out.
 */
public class JobExample {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobExample.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ConfigBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigBuilder();
        if (args.length > 0) {
          configBuilder.withMasterUrl(args[0]);
        }
        try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient(configBuilder.build())) {
          final String namespace = "default";
          final Job job = new JobBuilder()
            .withApiVersion("batch/v1")
            .withNewMetadata()
            .withName("pi")
            .withLabels(Collections.singletonMap("label1", "maximum-length-of-63-characters"))
            .withAnnotations(Collections.singletonMap("annotation1", "some-very-long-annotation"))
            .endMetadata()
            .withNewSpec()
            .withNewTemplate()
            .withNewSpec()
            .addNewContainer()
            .withName("pi")
            .withImage("perl")
            .withArgs("perl", "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)")
            .endContainer()
            .withRestartPolicy("Never")
            .endSpec()
            .endTemplate()
            .endSpec()
            .build();

          logger.info("Creating job pi.");
          client.batch().v1().jobs().inNamespace(namespace).createOrReplace(job);

          // Get All pods created by the job
          PodList podList = client.pods().inNamespace(namespace).withLabel("job-name", job.getMetadata().getName()).list();
          // Wait for pod to complete
          client.pods().inNamespace(namespace).withName(podList.getItems().get(0).getMetadata().getName())
            .waitUntilCondition(pod -> pod.getStatus().getPhase().equals("Succeeded"), 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

          // Print Job's log
          String joblog = client.batch().v1().jobs().inNamespace(namespace).withName("pi").getLog();
          logger.info(joblog);

        } catch (KubernetesClientException e) {
            logger.error("Unable to create job", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Option : 2**

You can also apply the **YAML** file

```
ApiClient client = ClientBuilder.cluster().build(); //create in-cluster client
Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);
BatchV1Api api = new BatchV1Api(client);

V1Job job = new V1Job();
job = (V1Job) Yaml.load(new File("<YAML file path>.yaml")); //apply static yaml file
    
ApiResponse<V1Job> response = api.createNamespacedJobWithHttpInfo("default", job, "true", null, null);
```

Comment: The response above is for how to create a job using Java.but in my case already job has been created i just need an API to trigger it whenever i need it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as you since it was needed for me and my team, to develop a web application, that makes it possible for any user to start a new execution from our jobs.

> I have a job already running in Kubernetes which is scheduled for 4 hours.

If I'm not mistaken, it's not possible to schedule a Job on Kubernetes, you need to create a Job from a CronJob, that's our case.
We have several CronJobs scheduled to start through the day, but it's also needed to start it again, during some error or something else.

After some research, I decided to use the [Kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java) library.

When it was needed to trigger a job manually, I used to use kubectl CLI `kubectl create job batch-demo-job --from=cronjob/batch-demo-cronjob -n ns-batch-demo` , so I was also seeking for a way that makes that possible.

From an [issue](https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client/issues/443) opened on the Kubernetes-client GitHub it is not possible to do that, you need to search for your cronJob, then use the spec to create your job.

So I've made it a POC and it works as expected, it follows the same logic, but in a more friendly way.

In this example, I just need the cronJob spec to get the volume tag.

```
fun createJobFromACronJob(namespace: String) {
    val client = Config.defaultClient()
    Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client)


    try {
        val api = BatchV1Api(client)
        val cronJob = api.readNamespacedCronJob("$namespace-cronjob", namespace, "true")
        val job = api.createNamespacedJob(namespace, createJobSpec(cronJob), "true", null, null, null)
    } catch (ex: ApiException) {
        System.err.println("Exception when calling BatchV1Api#createNamespacedJob")
        System.err.println("Status Code: ${ex.code}")
        System.err.println("Reason: ${ex.responseBody}")
        System.err.println("Response Header: ${ex.responseHeaders}")
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
}

private fun createJobSpec(cronJob: V1CronJob): V1Job {
    val namespace = cronJob.metadata!!.namespace!!
    return V1Job()
        .kind("batch/v1")
        .kind("Job")
        .metadata(
            V1ObjectMeta()
                .name("$namespace-job")
                .namespace(namespace)
                .putLabelsItem("app.kubernetes.io/team", "Jonas-pangare")
                .putLabelsItem("app.kubernetes.io/name", namespace.uppercase())
                .putLabelsItem("app.kubernetes.io/part-of", "SINC")
                .putLabelsItem("app.kubernetes.io/tier", "batch")
                .putLabelsItem("app.kubernetes.io/managed-by", "kubectl")
                .putLabelsItem("app.kubernetes.io/built-by", "sinc-monitoracao")
        )
        .spec(
            V1JobSpec()
                .template(
                    podTemplate(cronJob, namespace)
                )
                .backoffLimit(0)
        )
}

private fun podTemplate(cronJob: V1CronJob, namespace: String): V1PodTemplateSpec {
    return V1PodTemplateSpec()
        .spec(
            V1PodSpec()
                .restartPolicy("Never")
                .addContainersItem(
                    V1Container()
                        .name(namespace)
                        .image(namespace)
                        .imagePullPolicy("Never")
                        .addEnvItem(V1EnvVar().name("TZ").value("America/Sao_Paulo"))
                        .addEnvItem(V1EnvVar().name("JOB_NAME").value("helloWorldJob"))
                )
                .volumes(cronJob.spec!!.jobTemplate.spec!!.template.spec!!.volumes)
        )
}
```

You also can use the Kubernetes client from [Fabric8](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client), it's great too, and easier to use.